# In Excel, how can I write a formula to track the evolution of issue tickets over time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a basic ticket tracking report. We would like to see this information (to begin):

```
# of tickets left open at end of last week - 3/10:

# of new tickets - 3/13:
# of tickets closed - 3/13:

# of new tickets - 3/14:
# of tickets closed - 3/14:

# of new tickets - 3/15:
# of tickets closed - 3/15:

# of new tickets - 3/16:
# of tickets closed - 3/16:

# of new tickets - 3/17:
# of tickets closed - 3/17:
```

A sample data set:

```
Record ID,Date,Part of Day,Status,Severity
4231843,3/10/2017,PM,Open,High
3423543,3/13/2017,AM,Closed,Medium
4231843,3/13/2017,PM,Open,High
4231843,3/13/2017,AM,Open,High
6231847,3/14/2017,AM,Closed,Low
```

How can I write a formula for each report metric? Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS` as appropriate

Comment: Use countifs() and concantenate the results with the text.

Comment: Or perhaps a pivot table?

Comment: It would be beneficial for you to share how the data set is populated. It could be one of these: **1**: is an entry made only when a ticket is opened/closed; **2**: or is an entry made when a ticket is opened, closed, and entries made for each open ticket each day? It feels like option 2 is how it works, given the multiple entries for ticket 4231843. Ideally, if the status could be changed to `New` for every new ticket added that would simplify your [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842) logic tremendously.

Comment: Thanks everyone for this info. I can try to use COUNTIF and COUNTIFS to start. How can I do this with a range of data?

Comment: COUNTIFS documentation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842 The syntax of it is `COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)`. You'd use `criteria_range1` as the column with dates, `criteria1` as a date value - this will match the rows with that date. Then, `criteria_range2` as the status column, `criteria2` as `Open` or `Closed`.